# Is there any way I can have an out of band certification of a site's self signed certs?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

Sometimes given the laws and the circumstances one is subjected to, obtaining an official SSL Certificate for a webservice might be extraordinarily difficult if not illegal.

For those who are stuck with having to self-sign their sites, is there anyway of providing my certificate to an out-of-band verification or authority service? This way my users can verify that a MiM attack hasn't been performed?

While I can think of one way this might be abused, it would at least provide a bit more clarity on self-signed certs. Or is there something I'm failing to consider regarding this hypothetical?

I'm imagining this would look simular to how public BitTorrent tracker servers work. Where everyone who wants to verify a site's self-signed cert would add this "self-signed certification grating 'authority'" as a trusted-root authority. Of course there would still need to be some notification to the user that a self-cert is being used. Maybe like a orange pad-lock icon...

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how CA's work. You create keys, send to a CA to verify, they send you a cert. Your visitors use their own installed root certs to verify the cert they get from your server. You're basically asking for PKI to exist, when it already does.

Comment: Certs do not protect against MitM. Locking those certs to a site does. So, your requested process won't protect against MitM. that's a separate process.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I didn't understand the CA process and was reinventing the wheel.

Comment: And sure, you can use, or create, a CA, but then all your users would have to trust that root CA's certs and install them.

Comment: Have a look at at [DANE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Authentication_of_Named_Entities) (certificates in DNS) and [various papers etc about certificates on the blockchain](https://www.google.com/search?q=x509+pki+certificate+blockchain) for something which addresses your problem. So it is doable in theory.

Comment: I think that and specific answer here would depend on what it means that getting a signed cert is difficult or illegal. Because depending on why it was difficult or illegal, those reasons might prevent any other solution. Including having self-signed certs.